# Where should a mongodb process be started for a node application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I want my application server(Hapi/Express) to start the mongodb process before proceeding with server.start(). A good way to do this is via Promises so that the mongod return code can be captured in .then and checked for start success/failure.

---

I posted a similar question @ [Nodejs exec mongodb command in Bluebird Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100509/nodejs-exec-mongodb-command-in-bluebird-promise), that prompted me to ask this one here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to not understand the basics of processes.

> so that the mongod return code can be captured in .then

`mongod` will not return any code until it exits (it's called "exit code" for a reason). I assume that you want your mongodb running, so this means no code for you.

Starting a database server from the application is absolutely the wrong way to do it. Database and application should be started separately (by OS' startup manager or whatever). If you install mongodb from a package, the auto-startup should be handled for you (via installing proper init script).

Application should only know a connection string (and if it can't connect to the database at this string, show some pretty error message).

Comment: Understand the mongod exit code. So, the application has to do a service/process look up to check mongod's availability? For a gracious handle, should it also keeping check the process periodically?

Comment: Nope, it's not application's concern to monitor DB availability either. You just connect and do your queries. If you can't connect, show error message.